# Пролема с путями к видам в модуе yii2

Tags: yii2

Сгенерировал через `gii` модуль `admin`. Однако при попытке посетить страницу модуля выкидает ошибку `The view file does not exist: D:\OpenServer\domains\yii.loc\modules\admin\views\site/search.php`
хотя в методе `actionIndex` контроллера `DefaultControler` только `return $this->render('index');`  При этом запускаеться точно он и такой вид точно существует. В случае когда я пишу имя вида которого нет, ошибка адекватная `The view file does not exist: D:\OpenServer\domains\yii.loc\modules\admin\views\default\wrong-view.php`. При использовании абсолютного пути при рендеринге поведение такое-же. В чём дело?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в конфиг, в массив **modules** добавить этот модуль

```
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Admin',
    ],
],
```

Учтите, что название класса должно соответствовать его namespace`у.
В данном случае, убедитесь, что

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin;

/**
 * admin module definition class
 */
class Admin extends \yii\base\Module
```

Comment: конфиг у меня настроен, с неймспейсами все в порядке.

Comment: А модуль у вас в корне в **modules** или во **frontend** \ **backend** ?

Comment: @СергейО Вот еще раз специально создал модуль через GII.
Модуль лежит во **frontend/modules/admin/Admin.php**, 
**app\modules\admin\Admin**. Прописываю в **frontend/main/config/main.php** `'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Admin',
        ],
    ],` и все работает

Comment: у меня в лайауте методом $this->render() ищеться этот вид. а ссылка там относительная.

Answer (score 0):

Я все понял. Я пока использую стандартный лайаут, а там этот вид с формой для поиска через $this->render(). И вот он и ищеться.